# Fingerpint Authentication without pop-up dialog [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using local_auth library for fingerprint authentication. Is there any way to authenticate user without any pop-up dialog, just listens authentication when opens the page (initializes at initState)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a plug in [Invisible Authentication](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_auth_invisible) that might be just the thing you want. There is no pop dialog for authentication.

Hope it helps.